# Flock error - bad number

Tags: flock

Im trying to create cronjob like this to prevent duplicate cronjobs from running:

> - - - - - flock -n /mydir/control.txt -c bash /mydir/script.sh

But its not working.

When i try command in console:

> flock -n /mydir/control.txt

I get error:

> flock: bad number: /mydir/control.txt

I was browsing web to find answer for my problems but i didnt find anything. What cause this error? How can i fix this?

Btw i use Debian 7 64bit

Comment: `-c` - pass a single command, without arguments. so `/mydir/script.sh` is being seen as an argument to flock, not to bash.

Comment: @marc-b Thanks  this solve problem but not fully.
flock -n /mydir/control.txt /mydir/script.sh is sometimes working, sometimes script.sh is not starting.